# How to save Javascript DOM elements, and their attributes using XML and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, dom

I am creating a sticky-note system for my website. I want to be able to create multiple new sticky-notes, write things on the sticky-notes, and be able to move the sticky-notes around.

^This far I have managed.

Next time I visit my website, I want the sticky-notes to be where I left them. How can I go about achieving this using Javascript, XML and PHP?

I'm guessing that I have to find a way to save the X and Y coordinates of each sticky-note in an XML document. How can I do this?

Comment: I would be careful saving the html because of XSS, Cross site Scripting.  If these sticky notes get shown to other uses beside the one that created them, you could embed JS code in them and steal client data from other users.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting  "roughly 84% of all security vulnerabilities documented by Symantec as of 2007"  A bit out of data quote but still relevant.

Comment: Only I will be able to acces the website as it will only be stored locally on my pc.

Comment: you can use the position in jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/position/  And this would be useful https://jqueryui.com/draggable/